# Wordpress show list of posts in user chosen categories

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, wp-list-categories

I am trying to make a system in which a user checks categories that he likes and after pressing the submit button a list of categories and their posts will appear. The categories will be the ones that the user checked. I have gotten as far as getting the category list from wordpress. I also added a submit button and when the user presses it a list appears with categories. The problem is that in each category it shows not the category specific posts but all posts. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
                            // get all the categories from the database
                $cats = $postCategories;

                        // loop through the categries
                        foreach ($cats as $cat)
                        {
                            // setup the cateogory ID and Name
                                        $cat_name= get_cat_name($cat);
                            $cat_id= get_cat_id($cat);

                            // Make a header for the cateogry
                            echo "<h2>".$cat_name."</h2>";
                            // create a custom wordpress query

                          query_posts("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=100");
                            // start the wordpress loop!
                            if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                                <?php // create our link now that the post is setup ?>

                                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                                <?php echo '<hr/>'; ?>

                            <?php endwhile; endif; // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>
                        <?php
                        } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

The $postCategories variable is a global from functions.php :

Functions.php code for this :

```
function get_categories_list() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['category-submit'] ) && '1' == $_POST['category-submit'] ) {
        if($_POST['post_category'] == null){
            echo"list empty";
        }else {
            global $postCategories;
            $postCategories = $_POST['post_category'];
            echo count($postCategories);
        }
    }
```

I just don't see where I made a mistake.

Comment: are you interested for use wordpress plugin or manually wordpress code integration?

Comment: right now I am interested in manually writing the code. What I have this far is I have made a new template file, and I got to display categories and posts related to those categories. Now what I must do is get the checklist in there and a button